# Finding elements that are algebraic over a given field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Find all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there exist elements in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}12]{2)}$ that are algebraic of order $k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. For each such $k$ find an example of such an element.

Let $a$ be such an element. From the formula [$\mathbb{Q}:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}12]{2}]=[\mathbb{Q}:\mathbb{Q}(a)][\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}12]{2})$ it follows that $k$ must be equal to 2, 3, 6, 12 or 4. I don't know where to go from here, nor do I know whether all such $k$ are viable. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $\theta=\sqrt[12]{2}$. What is the degree of $\theta^k$, when $k$ divides $12$?

Comment: Bonus points: What is the degree of $\theta^k$, when $k$ does not divide $12$?